# Simple transparency toggle with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, transparency

Hopefully a simple question with an equally simple answer...

I'm trying to make an autohotkey script to toggle window transparency.

Currently, I'm setting the active window transparency with the following:

```
^!RButton::WinSet, Transparent, 150, A
```

However, I'd like to extend this to toggle between 150 and 255, but am having a difficult time grasping how to toggle this.

---

**Edit:**  By toggle, I'm meaning hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd> once to set the transparency to 150, and then hitting it again to set the window back to full transparency.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this would probably do it (untested):

```
^!RButton::
WinGet, currentTransparency, Transparent, A
if (currentTransparency = OFF)
{
    WinSet, Transparent, 150, A
}
else
{
    WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another sample,

```
ClearTooltip:
  ToolTip
  return

>+>::
  ;ToolTip right shift + >
  WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
  return

>+<::
  ;ToolTip right shift + <
  WinGet, t, Transparent, A
  if (not t) {
    t := 250
  }
  t := t - 20
  WinSet, Transparent, %t%, A
  ToolTip %t%
  SetTimer, ClearTooltip, -321
  return
```

cf. https://superuser.com/a/582766/50938