# How can I make the whole Firefox window transparent?

Tags: windows, firefox

I am looking for an add-on or a solution for Firefox which enables transparency on the whole Firefox window.

It would be best if the degree of transparency could be adjusted and there were hot keys to quickly enable or disable the add-on.

Any idea?

Comment: I made that more general. You probably won't get far with a Firefox add-on, this will need some Windows tweaks. I assume Windows is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerMenu: http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/ would do what you would like.

Here are some alternatives as well: http://alternativeto.net/software/powermenu/

Comment: PowerMenu contains a trojan - what a `safe` free stuff! http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=175704ce1af2ab87d46f0070f540f753ec836b29835858b36124ba87eab357ad-1317325848

Comment: 1 of 41 scanners sounds like a false positive to me.

Comment: I didn't check for previous versions but latest Firefox (v34) can't be on top with PowerMenu.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted `PowerMenu` application didn't work for me. However, How-To Geek has the great solution via AutoHotkey. Just install AutoHotkey and save this script as a `.ahk` and execute it. You can then control the transparency of any Windows by holding the Win/Meta key and scrolling the mouse wheel. This is of course, adjustable by editing the script. This worked on every window I tried under Windows 7 x64.

```
; changing window transparencies
#WheelUp::  ; Increments transparency up by 3.375% (with wrap-around)
    DetectHiddenWindows, on
   WinGet, curtrans, Transparent, A
    if ! curtrans
        curtrans = 255
    newtrans := curtrans + 8
    if newtrans > 0
    {
        WinSet, Transparent, %newtrans%, A
    }
    else
    {
        WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
        WinSet, Transparent, 255, A
    }
return

#WheelDown::  ; Increments transparency down by 3.375% (with wrap-around)
    DetectHiddenWindows, on
    WinGet, curtrans, Transparent, A
    if ! curtrans
        curtrans = 255
    newtrans := curtrans - 8
    if newtrans > 0
    {
        WinSet, Transparent, %newtrans%, A
    }
    ;else
    ;{
    ;    WinSet, Transparent, 255, A
    ;    WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
    ;}
return

#o::  ; Reset Transparency Settings
    WinSet, Transparent, 255, A
    WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
return

#g::  ; Press Win+G to show the current settings of the window under the mouse.
    MouseGetPos,,, MouseWin
    WinGet, Transparent, Transparent, ahk_id %MouseWin%
    ToolTip Translucency:`t%Transparent%`n
    Sleep 2000
    ToolTip
return
```

[Source via howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44915/how-to-change-window-transparency-in-windows-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Modified AHK v1 [code](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/667-transparent-windows/?p=148102) for AHK v2

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Wheel Up/Down</kbd> keys to increase/decrease the transparency of an app or window.
- Use `MouseGetPos` to obtain window ID as a personal preference.
- 500ms tooltip

Show a pop-up menu with pre-defined transparency values when <kbd>F8</kbd> is pressed (inspired by [this](http://www.computoredge.com/AutoHotkey/Downloads/Always_on_Top.ahk) code)

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

^+WheelUp:: {           ; increases Trans value, makes the window more opaque
MouseGetPos ,, &WinID
; WinID := WinExist("A")  ; alternative - but 'Active' window might not always be the intended target
Trans := GetTrans(WinID)
If Trans < 255
    Trans := Trans + 20 ; add 20, change for slower/faster transition
If Trans >= 255
    Trans := "Off"
SetTransByWheel(Trans, WinID)
}

^+WheelDown:: {         ; decreases Trans value, makes the window more transparent
MouseGetPos ,, &WinID
Trans := GetTrans(WinID)
If Trans > 20
    Trans := Trans - 20 ; subtract 20, change for slower/faster transition
Else If Trans <= 20
    Trans := 1          ; never set to zero, causes ERROR
SetTransByWheel(Trans, WinID)
}

F8::SetTransMenuFn

;--------

GetTrans(id) {
Trans := WinGetTransparent("ahk_id " id)
If not Trans
    Trans := 255
Return Trans
}

;--------

SetTransByWheel(Transparency, id) {
If Transparency = "Off"
    WinSetTransparent 255, "ahk_id " id
    ; Set transparency to 255 before using Off - might avoid window redrawing problems such as a black background. If the window still fails to be redrawn correctly, try WinRedraw, WinMove or WinHide + WinShow for a possible workaround.
WinSetTransparent Transparency, "ahk_id " id
ToolTipFn("Transparency: " Transparency, -500)
}

;--------

SetTransMenuFn() {
MouseGetPos ,, &WinID   ; identify window id
; WinID := WinExist("A")  ; alternative - but 'Active' window might not always be the intended target
Global WinID            ; so that SetTransByMenu can use it to set transparency
SetTransMenu := Menu()
SetTransMenu.Delete
SetTransMenu.Add("&1 255 Opaque"            ,SetTransByMenu)
SetTransMenu.Add("&2 190 Translucent"       ,SetTransByMenu) ; Semi-opaque
SetTransMenu.Add("&3 125 Semi-transparent"  ,SetTransByMenu)
SetTransMenu.Add("&4  65 Nearly Invisible"  ,SetTransByMenu)
SetTransMenu.Add("&5   1 Invisible"         ,SetTransByMenu) ; never set to zero, causes ERROR
SetTransMenu.Show
}

;--------

SetTransByMenu(item, position, SetTransMenu) {
Transparency := Trim(SubStr(item, 4, 3))
WinSetTransparent Transparency, "ahk_id " WinID
If Transparency = 255 {
    WinSetTransparent "Off", "ahk_id " WinID ; Specifying Off - may improve performance and reduce usage of system resources
    }
ToolTipFn("Transparency: " Trim(SubStr(item, 4)), -2000)
}

;--------

ToolTipFn(mytext, myduration) {
ToolTip ; turn off any previous tooltip
ToolTip mytext
SetTimer () => ToolTip(), myduration
}
```